# Maintaining array order with multiple faces using CIDetector Face Detection - iOS

Tags: ios, core-image, face-detection, gpuimage

I want to maintain the order of the NSArray I get back from CIDetector so I can tween the frames I draw in the camera view using an animation block. The problem is the order of faces is often different in every array I get back, and as you can imaging this voids the proper animation with multiple faces, especially when faces cross.

How do I maintain the same order of faces every time? Or is this even possible?

Here's the initialization I'm doing:

```
NSDictionary *detectorOptions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:CIDetectorAccuracyLow, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];
self.faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];
```

And I get my array using this line:

```
NSArray *features = [self.faceDetector featuresInImage:convertedCIImage options:imageOptions];
```

I'm piping data to CIImage from GPUImage if that info helps.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the items in features as `CIFaceFeature` objects and use the `trackingID` property (iOS6+) to keep track of which faces are which, [more info](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html).

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that if a face goes off-frame and comes back on, it will still have a unique id, but not the *same* id it had before.